# for above href im using below code in selenium web drive but its not clicking on href link

Tags: selenium

```
<li>
<a href="/digidms/order/preCreateBlanketOrder">Create Blanket Purchase Order - Program</a>
</li>
```

for above `href` im using below code in `selenium web drive` but its not clicking on href link..

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create Blanket Purchase Order - Program")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

if doing it in python, selenium webriver in python doesn't have findElement method.

so it would be

```
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//a[contains(text(),'Create Blanket')]")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try either of the codes to click on the link:

**1-** **Clicks on the 'a' element with exact innerHTML or text as 'Create Blanket Purchase Order - Program' :-**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Create Blanket Purchase Order - Program']")).click();
```

**2-** **Clicks on the 'a' element that contains 'Create Blanket' as part of its innerHTML/text :-**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Create Blanket')]")).click();
```

**3- Clicks on the 'a' element that contains 'preCreateBlanketOrder' as part of its 'href' attribute :-**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'preCreateBlanketOrder')]")).click();
```

**4- Clicks on the 'a' element that contains 'preCreateBlanketOrder' as part of its 'href' attribute and contains 'Create Blanket' as part of its innerHTML/text :-**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'preCreateBlanketOrder') and contains(text(),'Create Blanket')]")).click();
```

Comment: Downvoter, please state the reason for downvoting.. Downvoting without any reason doesn't help out a person to correct what's wrong.. If you don't care to point out what's wrong, you have no right to downvote here..